# Why are the FB share icons being hidden with lazy loading/ jscroll / ajax loaded elements?

Tags: ajax, facebook, share

I had lazy loading on my page and was trying to place a share button in one of the elements but it won't display for some reason. I encountered this issue a day back and spent few hours trying to figure why the FB share buttons won't load. I couldn't find any issues here as well so I thought I'll post the case along with the solution so someone in need may save some time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the social media share buttons make a request through the script to load html element like the image etc for loading the buttons. So when you load a page through ajax, you must re initiate the FB object before you use it in your call for the share button.

```
function loadFacebook()
{
    if (typeof (FB) != 'undefined') {
        FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    } else {
        $.getScript("http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1", function () {
            FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        });
    }
}
```

Calling the above function just before the new page loads did the job for me. You can go through this wonderful article on [Lazy Load Social Media Buttons](http://www.paulund.co.uk/lazy-load-social-media) for more details. I found the solution in the same article.

Comment: _“you must re initiate the FB object”_ – no, that’s not the proper way to do it. See the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will incorporate the required changes to my code as well